# Hiding the required menu items for the particular user in angular 2

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have created an angular application in which I have a login form where i have implemented authentication using service and guard .

I have defined a interface user with username and password.Using this interface in **authentication.service.ts** I have defined two users **admin** and **user**.

I have also implemented a guard named **authentication.guard.ts** where I have taken **CanActivate** RouteGaurd to route the user to the page which he can access.

In my application there is an admin page which can only be accessed by **admin** user, so if the admin logs in only then it navigates to **Admin Page** .If **user** logs in then he will be redirected to **Home Page** skipping the **Admin Page**

When a **admin**  or **user** logs into the application, a menu bar appears where I have three menu items **Home, AdminActivity ,RegisterUser** .

I am trying to hide the **AdminActivity** menu item if **admin** logs into the application and hide the **RegisterUser** menu item if **user** logs into the application.

I tried to import the authentication service in **app.component.ts** but I am unable to fetch the logged username and password.

Can anybody please help me out in implementing the desired functionality as I needed to implement in my application

Please access my sample application [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: is username being saved in local storage?

Comment: @AbdulRafay..... yes ..... as shown in authentication.service.ts..........let authenticatedUser = users.find(u => u.username === this.user.username);
    if( authenticatedUser && authenticatedUser.password==this.user.password ){
    localStorage.setItem("user", this.user.username);
    this._router.navigate(['/Admin']); }

Comment: update your code to check admin user with local storage as:
isSuperAdmin() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') === "admin") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

Comment: @Heena Please consider posting your code in your **question** by clicking on the _edit_ link located just underneath your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated your sample code [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/role-based-authentication-74qqf9?file=app/authentication/authentication.service.ts)**

Used a [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) for tracking user type and used it to show/hide menu items. You can use it for communicating within different components throughout the app. I removed some of your code which was causing errors in Stackblitz but don't focus on that.

**Changes in `AuthenticationService`:**

declared `userType` [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) as:

```
  userType: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.getUserType());
```

added method to get user type from local storage as:

```
  getUserType() {
    return localStorage.getItem('user')
  }
```

updating `userType` [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) in login:

```
login(username, password) {
...
localStorage.setItem("user", this.user.username);
this.userType.next(this.user.username);
```

**Changes in `app.componet.ts`:**

subscribing to `userType` [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject):

```
  userType: string = '';

  ngOnInit(){
    ...
    this.authService.userType.subscribe(value => this.userType = value);
  }
```

**Changes in `app.componet.html`:**

show/hide menu items with `*ngIf`:

```
  <button *ngIf="userType === 'admin'" mat-raised-button routerLink='application/AdminAccess/admin-activity' routerLinkActive="active">Admin Activity </button>

  <button *ngIf="userType === 'user'" mat-raised-button routerLink='application/UserManagement/add-users' routerLinkActive="active">Register User</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback .. its working exactly what i needed... I modified the changes in my earlier application and its working fine .. thanks a lot again..

Answer (score 0):

Since your stackbliz is not working, but below I would like to provide some useful code:-

In your routing.module.ts, modify your 'Admin' route,

```js
{path:'Admin',component: AdminComponent,
data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
},
canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]}
```

In your authenticationguard.guard.ts, modify like below:-

```js
 constructor( private auth: AuthenticationService,  private _router: Router) {} 
    
 

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Promise<boolean> {

        const authorities = route.data['authorities'];
        // here you get authorities user role name, now you can apply your service logic
         if (!this.auth.isSuperAdmin(authorities)) { // add arg in isSuperAdmin to validate username
      this._router.navigate(['/application/home']);
      return false; 
    }
    
    return true;
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thankyou for your response... when I am modifying my authenticationguard.guard.ts , its resulting in following error in my console..... Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signatu
re. Type 'Boolean' has no compatible call signatures.